# Layout looks different?

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-layout, android-studio

I know that layouts can look different on different screen sizes, but I didn't take that into account when I made this layout. So, it is designed for normal screen size, by default, and my phone screen is also normal.

The problem is, the layout looks different then it should be. Here is how it is on my phone, notice that **the four image buttons are slightly to the right**

[image]

Here is what it should be like, as shown in android studios layout tool. **Notice, it is nicely centered, as it should be**:

[image]

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ruchir.circleswithmap.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="73dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bluecircle" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/Green"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Blue"
        android:background="@drawable/greencircle" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/Red"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Blue"
        android:background="@drawable/redcircle" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/Purple"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Green"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Red"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Red"
        android:background="@drawable/purplesquare" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why is this? How can I fix it so that the layout on my phone is also centered, as it should be? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Post the xml for your layout, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Paste your xml layout. so we can help

Comment: @TedHopp I'm sorry. I have updated my question! :)

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi I'm sorry. I have updated my question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
android:gravity="center"
```

to your RelativeLayout to center the content of the layout and remove the

```
android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
android:layout_marginStart="73dp"
```

from the first ImageButton if you want to center it horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Thank you, I have marked best answer. Why was this happening anyway?

Comment: @NullPointerException - It was happening because you were hard-coding margin sizes. Emanuel's solution lets the layout compute the appropriate margins for the actual screen size.

Comment: It wasn't centered because you didn't center it ;-). You can't use margins to center views since screens can have different resolutions and the margins would have to be different too.